# Error: Must install SSIS log provider for SQL Server of Integration Services

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

When I execute a package in VS 2019 with SSIS extension installed I get this message

```
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility
Version 12.0.5626.31 for 32-bit
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Started:  14:54:58
Log:
     Name: OnError
     Computer: xxxxxxxx
     Operator: xxxxxxxx
     Source Name: xxxxxxx
     Source GUID: {4B63A6C1-E0E4-4ADB-82B6-E86A0970C537}
     Execution GUID: {2259AE3B-7C3E-447F-A210-085BB1684808}
     Message: To run a SSIS package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you must install Provedor de log SSIS log para o SQL Server of Integration Services or higher.
```

I have these providers:

[image]

And these connection managers:

[image]

Why does it think I'm `outside of SQL Server Data Tools`? I guess I am. I already searched and none of the answers fits my case. What should I check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're clicking Start without Debugging given the pretty text output?

[image]

If so, that's running the package outside of Visual Studio, even though you launched it from Visual Studio... To be able to run a package without debugging, whether it's from Visual Studio or just the command line, a licensed install (Developer edition works fine and is cheap) of SQL Server Integration Services Service needs to exist.

Logging is likely installed correctly, that's just the first error it happened to report but searching here or dba.stackexchange on "To run a SSIS package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you must install" {Any component here} will all circle back to the same root issue - SSIS Service isn't installed and dtexec or the object model Application/package are trying to run a package and that's the poor error message reported.

Comment: _I assume you're clicking Start without Debugging given the pretty text output?

If so, that's running the package outside of Visual Studio, even though you launched it from Visual Studio..._ Makes a lot of sense. Yes Ctrl-F5.